# I don't know what's wrong with my coding. (javascript)

Tags: javascript

```
function calculateBmr(){
var weight = prompt("Enter weight in pounds");
var height = prompt("Enter height in inches");
var age = prompt("Enter age");
var bmr = 655 + (4.35 * weight) + (4.7 * height) - (4.7 * age);
alert("Your BMR is" bmr " calories.");
}
calculateBmr();
```

What's wrong with my code? It won't run.

Comment: I would suggest using your browser's javascript debugging console whenever you test your Javascript in the browser. Every modern browser has one and it will tell you where you are errors are accuring and why.

Answer (score 6):

```
alert("Your BMR is" bmr " calories.");
```

should be

```
alert("Your BMR is" + bmr +" calories.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function calculateBmr(){
    var weight = parseFloat(prompt("Enter weight in pounds"));
    var height = parseFloat(prompt("Enter height in inches"));
    var age = parseFloat(prompt("Enter age"));
    var bmr = 655 + (4.35 * weight) + (4.7 * height) - (4.7 * age);
    alert("Your BMR is " + bmr.toString() + " calories.");
}
calculateBmr();
```

The `parseFloat`s will ensure that what the user enters is a number and `+` ought to be used for string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

alert("Your BMR is" +bmr+ " calories.");

you have to use the operator +

> +bmr+